# What is the easiest way to get a Kafka cluster in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm writing a Flink application on Kubernetes which reads and writes to Kafka, so I need a Kafka cluster for testing purposes. I just want to find the easiest way to have a Kafka cluster running in Kubernetes, it could be just a single node cluster, performance is not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely check https://strimzi.io/ , it is a Kubernetes Kafka Operator

check this out: https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/minikube/

Comment: Is there a way I can use Strimzi with an already running kafka/zookeeper cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use [Helm](https://github.com/helm/helm) to deploy and use charts already tested and supported by big companies and the community.

I can highlight two of them:

**1 - [confluentinc/cp-helm-charts](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts)**

> The Confluent Platform Helm charts enable you to deploy Confluent
>   Platform services on Kubernetes for development, test, and proof of
>   concept environments.

Although this chart is in developer preview  (not supported for production use), the Kafka stack is pretty stable, well documented and supported by the [Confluent Operator](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-operator). By default, some [commercially licensed components](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/image-reference.html#image-reference) are used, so make sure to tweak the settings to use the community licensed ones.

**2 - [bitnami/kafka](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka)**

> This chart bootstraps a Kafka deployment on a Kubernetes cluster using
>   the Helm package manager.
>
> Bitnami charts can be used with Kubeapps for deployment and management
>   of Helm Charts in clusters. This Helm chart has been tested on top of
>   Bitnami Kubernetes Production Runtime (BKPR). Deploy BKPR to get
>   automated TLS certificates, logging and monitoring for your
>   applications.

Comment: Any idea what's the most scaleable for production? (e.g. best monitoring, easy scaling setup etc.)